How can I use indicator color to unselected tab in tab bar without using custom tab bar
So I want the grey indicator color in unselected Text/tab I can do with custom tab bar but can we do with Tabbar view i try to create custom indicator but it is not working properly.
I want indicator on both tabs , just different foir both tabs
I try to apply custom indicator on indicator property with
indicator: CustomTabIndicator(
                    height: 4,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2.9,
                    selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
                  ),
this is indiactor i am calling 
class CustomTabIndicator extends Decoration {
  final double height;
  final double width;
  final int selectedIndex;

  const CustomTabIndicator({
    this.height = 4,
    this.width = 30,
    required this.selectedIndex,
  });

  @override
  BoxPainter createBoxPainter([VoidCallback? onChanged]) {
    return _CustomTabIndicatorPainter(
      height: height,
      width: width,
      selectedIndex: selectedIndex,
    );
  }
}

class _CustomTabIndicatorPainter extends BoxPainter {
  final double height;
  final double width;
  final int selectedIndex;

  _CustomTabIndicatorPainter({
    required this.height,
    required this.width,
    required this.selectedIndex,
  });

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Offset offset, ImageConfiguration configuration) {
    final Paint paint = Paint();
    final double tabWidth = configuration.size!.width;
    paint.color = Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      Rect greyRect = Offset(
            offset.dx + (tabWidth * i) + (tabWidth - width) / 2.5,
            configuration.size!.height - height - 8,
          ) &
          Size(width, height);
      canvas.drawRect(greyRect, paint);
    }

    paint.color = Colors.orange;
    Rect orangeRect = Offset(
          offset.dx + (tabWidth * selectedIndex) + (tabWidth - width) / 2.5,
          configuration.size!.height - height - 8,
        ) &
        Size(width, height);
    canvas.drawRect(orangeRect, paint));
  }
}



is something wrong or should d i do with custom tab bar

if you're simply trying to set the color for unselected tabs, you can use the 'dividerColor' parameter in the TabBar
 TabBar(
        tabs: [Text('tab1'), Text('tab2')],
        controller: _tabController,
        indicatorColor: Colors.blue,
        dividerColor: Colors.grey,
      ),

or if you want the selected and unselected tab colors to appear similar in size, you can also adjust the 'indicatorSize' parameter in the TabBar
 TabBar(
        tabs: [Text('tab1'), Text('tab2')],
        indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
        controller: _tabController,
        indicatorColor: Colors.blue,
        dividerColor: Colors.grey,
      ),


Ok I will try this, Thank you for help.
